# Join two tables using substr

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I have two tables:

**TABLEA**

```
JRNO    JSNO    TEXT
1955    7       S0042     1000122000
```

**TABLEB**

```
CODE    INV        TYPE
AWSE    1000122    CHE
```

I need to join the tables in order to have the relevant info:-

```
CODE    INV        TYPE    JRNO    JSNO
AWSE    1000122    CHE     1955    7
```

To do so, I use the following SQL:

```
SELECT CODE, INV, TYPE, JRNO, JSNO
FROM TABLEB
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLEA ON SUBSTR(TEXT,11,7) = INV
WHERE INV = ‘1000122’
```

However, the results are as follows:

```
CODE    INV        TYPE    JRNO    JSNO
AWSE    1000122    CHE
```

It seems the `"SUBSTR(TEXT,11,7) = INV"` is not responding.

Can someone help me?

Comment: @Cybernate has the correct answer, but the schema is messed up anyways. Text should be split into two columns: INV and whatever the last four characters are. And if they are numbers, they should be stored as numbers, not text.

Comment: try `LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLEA ON LOCATE(INV, TEXT) > 0` (more http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0000820.htm)

Comment: also, what is the data type of INV?

Comment: The suggested LOCATE doesn't work as well.

Comment: Is INV on TABLEB a character or numeric field?

Answer (score 2):

**Setup**

```
create table tablea (jrno smallint, jsno smallint, text char(32));
create table tableb (code  char(8), inv char(8),type char(3));
insert into tablea values (1955,7,'S0042     1000122000');
insert into tableb values ('AWSE', '1000122', 'CHE');
```

**Using Substring**

```
7: select code, inv, type, jrno, jsno
from tableb
left outer join tablea on substr(text,11,7) = inv
where inv = '1000122'
CODE    INV TYPE    JRNO    JSNO
====    === ====    ====    ====
AWSE        1000122     CHE 1955    7
```

**Using Locate**

```
select code, inv, type, jrno, jsno
from tableb
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLEA ON LOCATE('1000122', TEXT) > 0
CODE    INV TYPE    JRNO    JSNO
====    === ====    ====    ====
AWSE        1000122     CHE 1955    7
```

the first parameter in locate (the search workd) cannot be a column name, and thats why it didnot work when you tried it.

CCSID is a character encoding not a column data type, so unless the creation of the table is not similar to what I have, I dont see what's the problem. Can you please update us with the query you use to create your tables?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked what you get from:

```
SELECT JRNO, JSNO, TEXT, SUBSTR(TEXT, 11, 7) AS INV
  FROM TableA;
```

Does this produce what you expect?  If not, then that's why the query with a join didn't work either.

If it does produce what you expect, then it is not immediately obvious what is wrong.

Comment: I'll get '1000122' but when I try to join it, it doesn't get the final results.